# Spark: process columns of dataset loaded from text file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I am new to Spark and Scala and trying to understand what is the best way to manipulate tables loaded from csv. Let's say I have features dataset in csv format and I need to normalize values by column.

I start with this code

```
val rdd=sc.textFile("test.csv").map(_.split(","))
```

textFile slices data by rows. How do I bring all column values to reducer to calculate mean,count, max, min and normalized values? How can I produce tuples with column index keys?
Thanks

Comment: You have various choices: write your own class, use built in class called Row & Column, convert rdd to dataFrame by passing a Schema (automatically return Row objects). Or you can directly go to mllib and use objects like DenseVector

Comment: is there a simple way to produce key pairs with column number as a key and value, then make aggregations in reduceByKey part? I am looking for some simple way to subtract column average from any value in dataset just by using mappers/reducers on above rdd

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend looking at the [spark-csv package](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) on [spark-packages](http://spark-packages.org/) and the using that together with [Spark's DataFrames](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) you will be able to aggregations on the different columns you are interested in.

Comment: That about covers it.